# When Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 will have a final version?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 installation keeps asking me to update ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 extension, and it is always a preview version. When will it finally have a final version? Is there any roadmap? Right now it is asking me to install the file:

> DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.4.exe

Should I relax and just install the preview on my computer that I use for work?

Comment: just install VS2017

Comment: That is not an option; I only have a license for Visual Studio 2015.